# cumulative sum by date and for specific columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumsum

i have a dataframe df :

```
user     Date      col1   col2  col3
user1  01/01/2021   1       0    0
user1  02/01/2021   0       0    1
user1  02/01/2021   0       1    0
user1  03/01/2021   1       0    0
user1  05/01/2021   0       0    1
user2  01/01/2021   0       0    1
user2  02/01/2021   0       1    0
user2  05/01/2021   0       1    0
user2  07/01/2021   0       0    1
```

i want to mutate this dataset, so that contains only rows with 1 in cols 3 , and cumilative sum of the both columns col1 and col2 only if the date  is 2 days before the date of col3.

```
user     Date      col1   col2  col3
user1  02/01/2021   1       0    1
user1  05/01/2021   1       0    1
user2  01/01/2021   0       0    1
user2  07/01/2021   0       1    1
```

im trying to use `cumsum`

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('d')).cumsum().reset_index()
```

but how compute the cummulative sum only if col3 equal 1

Comment: `05/01/2021 ` I can't find this entry in the dataframe

Comment: @Pygirl yep , i fix it

Comment: I didn't get the cumsum concept for col1 and col2 can you tell me the logic? I will look at it at night when I will come back from the ofc.

Answer (score 0):

first step would be to filter out the 0's in col3:

```
df = df[df['col3']!=0]
```